# Python @property помогите разобраться

Tags: python, python-3.x

Собственно не могу с setter-ом разобраться. Т.е. по данному коду если я инициализирую экземпляр класса wall_e со значением -100, то значение у него должно быть 0. По книгам так на практике что то где то не контачит. Может кто сталкивался

```
class Robot:
    def __init__(self, power):
        self._power = power
    power = property()
    @power.setter
    def power(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            self._power = 0
        else:
            self._power = value
    @power.getter
    def power(self):
        return self._power
wall_e = Robot(-100)
#wall_e.power = 20
print(wall_e.power)
```

Comment: Не должно, потому что при инициализации вы не используете property и ставите `self._power` в обход него

Comment: @andreymal а можно поподробней?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, power):
    self.power = power
```

Comment: А Вы сами пробовали то что советуете ?

Comment: @ksantd https://ideone.com/6cmOSg

Comment: огромное спасибо за наглядный пример.